# Private Void Tick(); Not working

Tags: java, function

The function is not working any idea how to fix this.
If it helps I am using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gir2R7G9ws).

```
public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            delta--;
        }
        if (running) {
            render();
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick(); {

    }

    private void render(); {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrtegy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();



        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: 1. when I hover over private void it comes up with "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"
2.WHen I hover over tick/render it comes up with"The method tick() is undefined for the type Game" but isnt that defining it there?
In the tutorial I used it worked fine for him either I missed something or my computer is just messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your tick() and render() methods out of the run() method and remove semicolons from methods declarations.

```
public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            delta--;
        }
        if (running) {
            render();
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }
}

private void tick() {

}

private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrtegy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

Comment: No I cant do that because when I dont have the semicolons it says it needs them there, thats why I put it there in the first place. @MazzCris